# Arrays: accessing array elements by inverting the index variable with the array itself yields the same result

Tags: c

So the code looks like this (you can access this fiddle [here (Click me)](https://onlinegdb.com/By-hAaA4V):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 6, 2, 7, 3, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d ", i[a]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
6 2 7 3 5
6 2 7 3 5
```

Apparently, he made a mistake when indexing the array, and inverted the index variable with the array itself. What he found out is that it still prints the same values. 
This might be a silly question, but again, I don't know much about these types of cases, and this itches me to find out why it's happening what's happening here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x + y)` which is equivalent to `*(y + x)` which is equivalent to `y[x]`.